# Regular Expression not to replace words starting with letter Z

Tags: java, regex, for-loop

i want to make java coding for matching character and replace that char with something else

for ex

if i have a string saying `"abc defg hijk"`

so i m replacing each char with `a=1 b=2 c=3  till y=25`

so its output will be `"123 4567 891011"`

but whenever i found everywords of 1st
char staring from letter Z that words should not replace

i.e for ex= `"abc zdefg hijk"` it     output must be like this `"123 zdefg 891011"`

can any 1 please tell me how to do this ?

Comment: if(count>0)
{
str = "";
String str123=enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
     Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("z(\\w+)(\\s)").matcher(enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
     while(matcher.find())
     {
      str1=matcher.group(1);
      System.out.println("Z letter "+str1);
     }
     str=enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase().
       replace("a","1").
       replace("b","2").
       replace("c","3").
       replace("d","4").
       replace("e","5").
}

Answer (score 2):

I will not give the replacement logic (too much spoon-feeding) but I can show you how to find if a word begins with a `z`.

```
   public static void main(String args[]){
   String s = "abc zdefg hijk asdsaz";
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?!z)(\\w+)\\b");
  // \\b is word boundary matcher.
  // ?! negative lookahead and checks if a word doesn't start with z
  // //w+ matches one or more characters only if previuos condition holds true.
         Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
         while(m.find()){
             System.out.println(m.group());
         }
    }
```

O/P:

```
abc
hijk
asdsaz
```

Comment: Thank, for ur ans i already did this part but facing problem in replacing part in my code whenever i find Z char as starting letter my whole string wont replace